# How to assign dynamic value to "number-rows-spanned" in XSLT?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

**SubCount** is the value that i want to assign to number-rows-spanned in my XSLT.

My XML Model

```
XElement xSubCount = new XElement("SubCount", subElemList.Count.ToString());
```

Comment: I thought number-rows-spanned needed to be an integer and not a string?

Comment: If your question is about XSLT, then please post an example of the XML input, your XSLT sylesheet so far, and the expected output - see: [mcve].